# Laravel 5, Cannot use db:seed (Label DB already defined)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, seeding

I want to use php artisan db:seed command on my cmd but it said Label 'DB' already defined,

this is my SeederTableAnggota Code:

```
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    class SeederTableAnggota extends Seeder {
    Public function run()
{
    DB:table('anggota')->delete();
    $anggota= array(
    array('id'=>1,'nama'=>'Rizki Amelia Dewi','alamat'=>'Cilengsi'),
    array('id'=>2,'nama'=>'Dewi Ayunindita','alamat'=>'Jatinangor'),
    array('id'=>3,'nama'=>'Siti Hajar Riska','alamat'=>'Jakarta')       
        );
    DB:table('anggota')->insert('anggota');
    }
}
```

i already use $this->call('SeederTableAnggota') on my DatabaseSeeder.php.

And i already use composer dump-autoload on my cmd too.

So how can i use db:seed and why it said Label 'DB' already defined? thanks for your help and any help will be very useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you have written `DB:table(...)` instead of `DB::table(...)`.
You forgot a colon so PHP thought that it is a constant.

Your seeder seems to be too complicated. Do you have a model?

Comment: Oh thanks it works ,
actually i followed a tutorial books for beginner, and creating model its up on next part after this one. 
and tbh i think using this kind of input to table is not efficient, but i try it anyway, just wanna try the db::seed function that mentioned on the book. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

just completing your answer, in my case the problem was because I was typing db::seed when the correct one is db:seed ie I was putting :: when the correct one is : , silly mistake but when you are tired goes unnoticed.